# Show that if $f : G → H$ is a homomorphism, $ H$ is abelian and $ N $ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $Ker f$, then $N$ is normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Show that if $f : G → H$ is a homomorphism, $H$ is abelian and $N $ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $Ker f$, then $N$ is normal in $G$.
>
> (First Isomorphism Theorem) If $f: G→ H$ is a homomorphism of groups, then $f$ induces an isomorphism $G/Ker f\cong Im f$.
>
> Corollary 5.12. lf $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, then every subgroup of $G/N$
>   is of the form $K/N$, where$ K$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $N$. Furthermore, $K/N $ is normal in $G/N$ if and only if $K$ is normal in $G$.

Proof: Since $H$ is abelian, $f(H)$ is an abelian subgroup. (How?)
By the First Isomorphism Theorem $f(H) \cong G/Ker f$ (How?), and so it too is abelian. (How?) Thus for every $g ∈ G, n ∈ N$,
$$(gH)nH(g^{-1}H) = (gH)(g^{-1}H)nH = nH.$$

Therefore $(gH)(N/H)(g^{-1}H) = N/H $ and so $N/H$ is normal in $G/N$. From here Corollary-I.5.12 concludes $N$ must be normal in $G $ since $N/H$ is normal in $G/Ker f$.

Can anyone explain the (How?) parts ?
Or is there any other proof suggested, since I understood so little from this.

Comment: I've removed all the \quad and \qquad because it looked just weird, but if you want them feel free to rollback.

Comment: Where did you find this proof? Is it yours, a friend's, does it come from a book/lecture notes?

Comment: On mobile it is easier to read when i put some space btw words, otherwise i cannot clearly see what is written

Comment: It's from the solution manual

Comment: What is $f(H)$? Is $H$ a subgroup  of $G$?

Comment: The linked question has other proofs; for the proof in your post, there isn't much to explain, because the first part is just wrong. $f(H)$ doesn't make sense here, since $H$ is the codomain of $f$ rather than a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: There is a typo in your solution manual. It should be $f(G)$, *not* $f(H)$. You need to prove two things: (1) subgroup of an abelian group is abelian; and (2) if $f: G_1\longrightarrow G_2$ is an isomorphism of groups, and if $G_1$ (resp. $G_2$) is abelian, then so is $G_2$ (resp. $G_1$).